# Program to create equation from drawing a graph

Tags: matlab, plot, drawing, octave, equation-solving

I was wondering if anyone knows a program that could make an equation from having someone just drawing the plot.

Example:  I would like to just draw an image then have the program give me the equation below.  Is such a thing possible?

```
Equation given after drawing the plot.
x=16*sin(s)^3
y=13*cos(s)-6*cos(2*s)-2*cos(3*s)-cos(4*s)
-pi<s<pi step=.01
```

[image]

[link to plot](http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MiwiZXF4IjoiMTYqc2luKHMpXjMiLCJlcXkiOiIxMypjb3MocyktNipjb3MoMipzKS0yKmNvcygzKnMpLWNvcyg0KnMpIiwiY29sb3IiOiIjRkYwMDAwIiwic21pbiI6Ii1waSIsInNtYXgiOiJwaSIsInNzdGVwIjoiLjAxIn0seyJ0eXBlIjoxMDAwLCJ3aW5kb3ciOlsiLTQwLjk1OTk5OTk5OTk5OTk4IiwiNDAuOTU5OTk5OTk5OTk5OTgiLCItMjYuNTI2MTUzODQ2MTUzODMyIiwiMjMuODg2MTUzODQ2MTUzODMiXX1d)

Comment: Do you mean drawing from a set of points?

Comment: @m_power in the end it will be a set of points because the drawing has to be converted to x and y values, but I was wondering if a program was already out there.

Comment: @Jigg hahah In the spirit of today that was the example I chose to use

Comment: May be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449035/drawing-a-picture-with-equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some parametrized class of curves and fit them to the current drawing. Usually you use [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29) in this context. If you like to allow corners you should introduce some corner detection and work with piecewise splines.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for `Interpolation` methods and choose which ever that best suits you.
A good point for start would be [Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).

Fortunately most of those methods are built-in function in MATLAB.
You can also check some results and comparison of splines methods in here [Splines](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~gerhard/classes/331/lab/splines.html).